# Can a game mouse or magic trackpad improve editing experience of Pro tools on Windows 10 desktop?

Tags: pro-tools, windows, windows-10

I am using Pro Tools MP9 on a Windows 10 desktop (please note Desktop, not laptop). The editing experience for panning and zooming is terrible using a regular mouse. I always miss the trackpad/touchpad. I was wondering what kind of hardware should I purchase to ease my experience.

After doing a little research I found that Apple Magic Trackpad 2 can be hacked to work in Windows or some other Logitech touchpad that officially supports Windows. I also see some high precision gaming mice available for much lesser price.

I couldn't find any information on the web whether these would make any difference or whether pro tools would respond to the touchpad gestures like pinch zooming, panning etc.

What accessory should I purchase?